# Create new branch that contains diff of directory between 2 branches

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a project with multiple branches. I can see the commits that exist on `branch2`, but not on `branch1` with this command:

```
git log branch1..branch2 path/to/dir
```

I would like to create a new branch off of `branch1` containing the commits displayed when the above command is executed.

For instance:

**On branch1:**

```
git log path/to/dir
  commit1
  commit2
```

**On branch2:**

```
git log path/to/dir
  commit1
  commit2
  commit3
  commit4
```

Then the command I mentioned above would return the following:

```
git log branch1..branch2 path/to/dir
  commit3
  commit4
```

I would like to find a way to create a new branch with its base off of `branch1`, let's call it `integration-branch` that contains those 2 commits.

`git log` is probably not the correct first step here, but it helps me illustrate what I want to accomplish. I presume there is and advanced form of `git merge` that allows partial merging of a branch into another.

Another option for me would be to first create the `integration-branch` off of `branch1`, then, from `branch2` merge only the changes of `path/to/dir`

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Firstly, the output of the log command is literally a log. Presumably, you want the actual commits, not the log messages. Secondly, do you want just the matching commits?

Comment: Reworded the question and included example. Is this clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a new branch that starts at `branch1` and contains *only* the commits from `branch2` that touch `path/to/dir`. The best way to do this would be to use `git cherry-pick`. Here's how I would do it:

```
// create a new branch to work on
$ git checkout -b newbranch branch1
// grab the commit IDs we want and cherry-pick them
$ git cherry-pick $(git log --pretty=format:%H --reverse branch1..branch2 -- path/to/dir)
```

There's a potential for conflicts in files other than `path/to/dir` if commits that are not being selected attempt to introduce changes to those files that violate the preconditions of the patch because intervening commits have been skipped. Getting around that would require going through the interesting commits, generating patches limited to just the changes made to interesting files, and applying those manually in sequence, which could get somewhat tedious if we're talking about lots of commits here...

Comment: Yes, you understand it correctly. I knew about cherry picking, but was missing the subshell to get the set of commit ids. I'll give this a shot and will mark it as answered if it works. Thank you